# Using a Font Awesome Icon as the text of Bootstrap's file input's browse button

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, font-awesome-4

There is a way to change the default *"Browse"* text of Bootstrap's file input field's button, [see the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#translating-or-customizing-the-strings-with-html). Is there a way to use a [Font Awesome Icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) in place of *"Browse"*? (In an Angular 8 environment.)

---

**Edit after question has been closed:**

Sorry, I don't get how it's off-topic. Which part of it is not clear or doesn't fit in the guidelines?

In an Angular8 environment I'd like to achieve that instead of this:

[image]

this would show:

[image]

I hope it's clear now but I'm not sure, I didn't add any new information:)

Comment: Icons you can insert like `<i class="fa fa-icon-name"></i>` but you cannot use HTML when customizing the button's text.

Comment: That it's not for the text of the button.

Comment: I've voted for reopening. I think the closers don't realize that Bootstrap uses a CSS trick to show a different text than the naive file input text, which can't be customized easily. This is not actually a button. I've also added the tag CSS, because it's probably relevant.